# Apex pmd : Validate CRUD permission before SOQL/DML operation (rule: Security-ApexCRUDViolation)apex pmdApexCRUDViolation)

Tags: apex, pmd

**I have used WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED in the query still getting this error.Can someone suggest a solution?**

```
 Public void freezeMethod (){
        disabledFreez = true;
        
        try{
            
            Direct_Commission__c dcObj = new Direct_Commission__c();
            If(String.isNotBlank(TermName)){
                dcObj.Term__c = TermName;
            }
            
            
            Insert dcObj; <-- Error on this line
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello `SECURITY_ENFORCED` enforced Field-Level security. CRUD is object-level security. You need to check for the User's ability to Create/Read/Update/Delete SObject itself

```
if (!SObjectType.Direct_Commission__c.isCreateable()) {
  // handle no access case
}
```

Comment: That your user has no ability to `Insert` Direct_Commission__c

Comment: ytiq Thanks it worked. But I used !Direct_Commission__c.SObjectType.getDescribe().isCreateable().

Comment: Whatever you prefer)

Comment: Glad I was able to help